# Closest point of approach analyses in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets, `df1` and `df2` (example of data for both are below), `df1` with an animal track and `df2` with traffic data. I would like to calculate the spatial distance in meters or km between all the points in `df1` and `df2` as well as the time distance between all the points in `df1` and `df2`. Given threshold values for both, spatial distance and time distance, I would then like to obtain a dataframe in which I have all the original details of `df1`, all the original details of `df2` and the measured spatial and time distances for all the points within the reference values. I understand that closest point of approach analysis is more complicated and should take into account also the speed and direction opf movement but at the moment I only interested in something more basic.

So far I took a very basic approach.

My df1 has the following structure:

```
structure(list(animal_id = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"
), a.timestamp = c("04/06/2023 09:59", "04/06/2023 10:36", "04/06/2023 17:44", 
"04/06/2023 17:59", "04/06/2023 18:16", "04/06/2023 19:05", "04/06/2023 19:17", 
"04/06/2023 19:27", "04/06/2023 19:39", "04/06/2023 19:54", "04/06/2023 20:12", 
"04/06/2023 20:49", "04/06/2023 21:10", "04/06/2023 21:27", "05/06/2023 05:33", 
"05/06/2023 05:56", "05/06/2023 07:49", "05/06/2023 09:06", "05/06/2023 09:28", 
"05/06/2023 09:28", "05/06/2023 09:50", "05/06/2023 10:18", "05/06/2023 17:28", 
"05/06/2023 17:30", "05/06/2023 17:45", "05/06/2023 18:53", "05/06/2023 18:58", 
"05/06/2023 19:13", "05/06/2023 19:19", "05/06/2023 19:58", "05/06/2023 20:34", 
"05/06/2023 20:46", "05/06/2023 21:15", "06/06/2023 05:03", "06/06/2023 05:35", 
"06/06/2023 06:45", "06/06/2023 07:16", "06/06/2023 07:26", "06/06/2023 08:54", 
"06/06/2023 09:03", "06/06/2023 09:03", "06/06/2023 09:42", "06/06/2023 09:57", 
"06/06/2023 10:33", "06/06/2023 17:09", "06/06/2023 17:10", "06/06/2023 18:38", 
"06/06/2023 18:38", "06/06/2023 18:47", "06/06/2023 18:53"), 
    a.lon = c(5.0448, 5.0368, 5.0677, 5.0322, 5.036, 5.0978, 
    5.0961, 5.0744, 5.0912, 5.1021, 5.1031, 5.137, 5.1304, 5.1512, 
    5.0925, 5.1154, 5.1184, 4.919, 5.0385, 5.0522, 5.074, 5.0834, 
    4.9123, 4.8376, 5.0438, 5.1276, 5.1235, 5.0963, 5.0638, 5.0743, 
    5.0682, 5.0801, 5.0753, 5.2049, 5.256, 5.1945, 5.1644, 4.9771, 
    4.9459, 5.0129, 5.0106, 4.9942, 5.0162, 4.9964, 4.9258, 5.105, 
    4.9827, 5.1424, 5.1795, 5.1609), a.lat = c(42.8164, 42.8252, 
    42.8487, 42.8474, 42.8858, 42.8311, 42.8351, 42.8556, 42.8682, 
    42.8397, 42.8682, 42.8788, 42.8827, 42.8871, 42.8601, 42.8582, 
    42.8256, 42.9573, 42.8716, 42.8641, 42.8535, 42.8754, 43.0263, 
    43.0027, 42.8815, 42.8779, 42.8695, 42.8368, 42.811, 42.8337, 
    42.8103, 42.8027, 42.8086, 42.8339, 42.8534, 42.8345, 42.8069, 
    42.8238, 42.8132, 42.7813, 42.7807, 42.7697, 42.8026, 42.77, 
    42.641, 42.8736, 42.978, 42.9414, 42.945, 42.9716)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

df2 has the structure:

```
structure(list(traffic_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), t.timestamp = c("04/06/2023 10:11", 
"04/06/2023 10:48", "04/06/2023 17:56", "04/06/2023 18:11", "04/06/2023 18:28", 
"04/06/2023 19:17", "04/06/2023 19:29", "04/06/2023 19:39", "04/06/2023 19:51", 
"04/06/2023 20:06", "04/06/2023 20:24", "04/06/2023 21:01", "04/06/2023 21:22", 
"04/06/2023 21:39", "05/06/2023 05:45", "05/06/2023 06:08", "05/06/2023 08:01", 
"05/06/2023 09:18", "05/06/2023 09:40", "05/06/2023 09:40", "05/06/2023 10:02", 
"05/06/2023 10:30", "05/06/2023 17:40", "05/06/2023 17:42", "05/06/2023 17:57", 
"05/06/2023 19:05", "05/06/2023 19:10", "05/06/2023 19:25", "05/06/2023 19:31", 
"05/06/2023 20:10", "05/06/2023 20:46", "05/06/2023 20:58", "05/06/2023 21:27", 
"06/06/2023 05:15", "06/06/2023 05:47", "06/06/2023 06:57", "06/06/2023 07:28", 
"06/06/2023 07:38", "06/06/2023 09:06", "06/06/2023 09:15", "06/06/2023 09:15", 
"06/06/2023 09:54", "06/06/2023 10:09", "06/06/2023 10:45", "06/06/2023 17:21", 
"06/06/2023 17:22", "06/06/2023 18:50", "06/06/2023 18:50", "06/06/2023 18:59", 
"06/06/2023 19:05"), t.lon = c(5.5448, 5.5368, 5.5677, 5.5322, 
5.536, 5.5978, 5.5961, 5.5744, 5.5912, 5.6021, 5.6031, 5.637, 
5.6304, 5.6512, 5.5925, 5.6154, 5.6184, 5.419, 5.5385, 5.5522, 
5.574, 5.5834, 5.4123, 5.3376, 5.5438, 5.6276, 5.6235, 5.5963, 
5.5638, 5.5743, 5.5682, 5.5801, 5.5753, 5.7049, 5.756, 5.6945, 
5.6644, 5.4771, 5.4459, 5.5129, 5.5106, 5.4942, 5.5162, 5.4964, 
5.4258, 5.605, 5.4827, 5.6424, 5.6795, 5.6609), t.lat = c(42.1164, 
42.1252, 42.1487, 42.1474, 42.1858, 42.1311, 42.1351, 42.1556, 
42.1682, 42.1397, 42.1682, 42.1788, 42.1827, 42.1871, 42.1601, 
42.1582, 42.1256, 42.2573, 42.1716, 42.1641, 42.1535, 42.1754, 
42.3263, 42.3027, 42.1815, 42.1779, 42.1695, 42.1368, 42.111, 
42.1337, 42.1103, 42.1027, 42.1086, 42.1339, 42.1534, 42.1345, 
42.1069, 42.1238, 42.1132, 42.0813, 42.0807, 42.0697, 42.1026, 
42.07, 41.941, 42.1736, 42.278, 42.2414, 42.245, 42.2716)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

I can easily obtain what I need if I only want to calculate 1:1 spatial and time distances:

```
#load the necessary libraries
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

#load the necessary files
#df1<- read.csv(file.choose()) 
#df2<- read.csv(file.choose())

#merge the two data.frames
merged.df<- cbind(df1, df2)

#set the reference values
ref.dist <- 1000 #made up value
ref.time <- 1000 #made up value

#get the output
output<- merged.df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(spatial.dist = distHaversine(cbind(a.lon, a.lat), cbind(t.lon, t.lat))) %>%
  mutate(a.timestamp = as.POSIXct(a.timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
  mutate(t.timestamp = as.POSIXct(t.timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  mutate(time.dist = abs(difftime(a.timestamp, t.timestamp, units="mins"))) #%>%
  #filter(spatial.dist < ref.dist) %>%
  #filter(time.dist , ref.time)
```

This works with the sample `data.frames` but:

- it doesn't work with my real `data.frames` because they have different length
- it becomes very slow with my real data because I have hundred of thousands of data points for each `data.frame`
- how can I work on 1-to-many calculations?
  How can I speed up the process?
  How can I work with `data.frames` of different lengths?
  Shall I convert my latitudes and longitudes to a UTM format for better measurements of spatial distances?
  Is in principle my approach correct?

Comment: If you want to compare _every_ point in one data set to _every point_ in the other data set, then the number of comparisons will be the number of rows in the first data set _multiplied_ by the number of rows in the other data set. If you have 500,000 in each data set, this would be 250 **billion** comparisons. This will take a long time however you do it, and you will not be able to store the results in memory. Are you just needing a single time point / distance at which the two tracks were closest? That seems much more achievable.

Comment: @AllanCameron single time point / distance at which the two tracks were closest would be a great result

Comment: "[the] single time point / distance at which the two tracks were closest".  Even this needs further definition.  Do you mean the closest point of (any) two tracks, regardless of the time at which the locations were recorded or the distance between the two tracks that is the smallest over all recoded time points?  The expected output based on your dsample data would be more than helpful.

Comment: I am following the approach from https://www.int-res.com/articles/esr2015/27/n027p219.pdf where they identify the animal and traffic positions closest in time, and then the horizontal distance between the animal and the traffic was calculated based on these positions. They use a distance threshold of 1000 meters to define the CPA. My animal dataframe includes at the moment about 2500 positions. I can subset the traffic dataframe by traffic type and retain only those positions that are within a given buffer. This brings the traffic dataframe down to about 17K data point per vessel type

Comment: As is often stated by @rhijmans, if accurate distance is required, you'll want to stay in lon/lat, not convert to planer (UTM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{sf}`, you'd be able to use spatial join with `st_is_within_distance()` predicate, following should mimic your chosen approach:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# data.frames to sf objects
df1_sf <- 
  df1 |> 
  as_tibble() |>
  mutate(a.timestamp = dmy_hm(a.timestamp)) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("a.lon", "a.lat"), crs = "WGS84")


df2_sf <- 
  df2 |> 
  as_tibble() |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("t.lon", "t.lat"), crs = "WGS84") |>
  mutate(t.timestamp = dmy_hm(t.timestamp),
         # add a copy of geometry column so we'd still have that after spatial join
         t.geom = geometry) 

#set the reference values
ref.dist <- 60000 # meters
ref.time <- 1000 # minutes

filtered_sf <- 
  st_join(df1_sf, df2_sf, join = st_is_within_distance, dist = ref.dist, left = FALSE) |>
  mutate(dist = st_distance(geometry, t.geom, by_element = TRUE),
         time.diff = a.timestamp - t.timestamp) |>
  filter(time.diff <= dminutes(ref.time))
```

Resulting dataset:

```r
filtered_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 6 fields
#> Active geometry column: geometry
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 4.9942 ymin: 42.7697 xmax: 5.256 ymax: 42.8534
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 10 × 8
#>    animal_id a.timestamp                 geometry traffic_id
#>  * <chr>     <dttm>                   <POINT [°]>      <int>
#>  1 aaa       2023-06-05 20:46:00 (5.0801 42.8027)          2
#>  2 aaa       2023-06-05 20:46:00 (5.0801 42.8027)          2
#>  3 aaa       2023-06-06 05:03:00 (5.2049 42.8339)          2
#>  4 aaa       2023-06-06 05:35:00  (5.256 42.8534)          2
#>  5 aaa       2023-06-06 06:45:00 (5.1945 42.8345)          2
#>  6 aaa       2023-06-06 07:16:00 (5.1644 42.8069)          2
#>  7 aaa       2023-06-06 07:16:00 (5.1644 42.8069)          2
#>  8 aaa       2023-06-06 09:03:00 (5.0129 42.7813)          2
#>  9 aaa       2023-06-06 09:03:00 (5.0106 42.7807)          2
#> 10 aaa       2023-06-06 09:42:00 (4.9942 42.7697)          2
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: t.timestamp <dttm>, t.geom <POINT [°]>, dist [m],
#> #   time.diff <drtn>
glimpse(filtered_sf)
#> Rows: 10
#> Columns: 8
#> $ animal_id   <chr> "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "a…
#> $ a.timestamp <dttm> 2023-06-05 20:46:00, 2023-06-05 20:46:00, 2023-06-06 05:0…
#> $ geometry    <POINT [°]> POINT (5.0801 42.8027), POINT (5.0801 42.8027), POIN…
#> $ traffic_id  <int> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
#> $ t.timestamp <dttm> 2023-06-05 17:40:00, 2023-06-05 17:42:00, 2023-06-05 17:40…
#> $ t.geom      <POINT [°]> POINT (5.4123 42.3263), POINT (5.3376 42.3027), POINT (5.…
#> $ dist        [m] 59551.12 [m], 59464.02 [m], 58941.71 [m], 59991.31 […
#> $ time.diff   <drtn> 3.100000 hours, 3.066667 hours, 11.383333 hours, 11.916667 h…
```

Visualize:

```r
library(mapview)
mv_1 <- 
  df1_sf |>
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING") |> 
  mapview(layer.name = "df1")

mv_2 <- 
  df2_sf |>
  group_by(as.factor(traffic_id)) |>
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) |>
  st_cast("LINESTRING") |>
  mapview(layer.name = "df2 (traffic_id)")

mv_1 + mv_2 + 
  mapview(filtered_sf, layer.name = "df1 points", col.regions = "gold") +
  mapview(st_set_geometry(filtered_sf, "t.geom"), layer.name = "df2 matches", col.regions = "lightyellow")
```

[image]

2nd dataset seems to be derived from the first; having real-world data for both might provide some additional context and perhaps somewhat more useful answers.

Also, trajectory analysis is quite a common discipline, so perhaps it's worth checking specialized packages and proven workflows - [CRAN Tacking task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Tracking.html) and [Spatio-Temporal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html)

Comment: Thanks @margusl, this was of great help. Definitely faster than my approach, I guess using sf objects and spatial indexes maked the entire proces quicker. My two data.frames have an average of about 350k-400k datapoints each and the calculations only take a couple of minutes. And yes, you are correct, the two data.frames I originally shared were derived one frtom the other just to provide example data.